# Perl: close open2 handle from a background thread

Tags: multithreading, perl, handle

I am simply trying to find out how to properly use the `open2` function.

See an example below. It works for a small `$max`, but naturally, if I write long enough to the `$hIn`, so eventually it will get blocked because nothing reads the data on the output continuously.

```
use 5.26.0;
use IPC::Open2;
my $max = 100000;
my $pid = open2(my $hOut, my $hIn, "cat") || die "failed 'cat': $!";
{
    my $cnt = 0;
    #When $max is big (e.g. 100000) so the code below will get blocked
    #when writing to $hIn
    while ($cnt<$max) {say $hIn $cnt++;}
    close($hIn) || say "can't close hIn";
}
while(<$hOut>) { print; }
close($hOut) || say "can't close hOut";
waitpid( $pid, 0 );
```

The only solution, that I can think about, is launching an other thread that will do the writing on the background.

With the code below I can write into the `$hIn` as much data as I want and read them in the main thread but the `$hIn` seems not to get closed. Because of that the `while(<$hOut>)` will never finish while waiting for more output.

```
use 5.26.0;
use threads;
use IPC::Open2;
my $max = 100000;
my $pid = open2(my $hOut, my $hIn, "cat") || die "failed 'cat': $!";
my $thr = threads->create(sub {
    my $cnt = 0;
    while ($cnt<$max) {say $hIn $cnt++;}
    #The close does not have any effect here (although no error is produced)
    close($hIn) || say "can't close hIn";
});
#This outputs all the data written to $hIn but never leaves the loop...
while(<$hOut> ) { print; }
close($hOut) || say "can't close hOut";
$thr->join;
waitpid( $pid, 0 );
```

My questions are:

- Provided that my approach with threads is ok, how can I close the file handle from the background thread?
- If it is not ok (actually `use threads` is discouraged in Perl), so can someone provide a working example of open2 that can write and read a lot of data without a risk of getting blocked waiting for the reader or writer?

---

EDIT: Following your suggestions here is an implementation of the code above using IPC::Run:

```
use 5.26.0;
use IPC::Run qw/ run /;
my $max = 1000000;
run sub {
        my $cnt = 0;
        while ($cnt<$max) {say $cnt++;}
    },
    "|", "cat",
    "|", sub {
        while(<> ) {
            print;
        }
    }
    or die "run sub | cat | sub failed: $?";
```

It runs without flaws, the code is very readable... I am very happy to have learned about this module. Thanks to everyone!

Yet, I consider the question to be unanswered. If it is not possible to write this functionality using `open2` directly, why does that even exist and confuse people? Also not being able to close the file handle from a different thread looks like a bug to me (certainly it is - the close should at least report an error).

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  The docs all but tell us not to use this, warn of deadlocks, and have a particular mention of precisely `cat` with regards to buffering.  I'd suggest  [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run)  or the simpler [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3)

Comment: Threads are just fine, if you know what you are doing. In Perl they come with a handful of gotchas but it's an advanced topic in any language or tool.  There are frameworks of various kinds which provide async capabilities, but then you have to learn how to use those.

Comment: Why are you printing so much without reading?  If the purpose is to pass a lot of data, there are better ways; it has to block if there's no reading. If you wish to feed a process and read from it, the linked modules are far nicer for that.

Comment: You might be able to use select to choose wether to read or write at a particular time. My best results with open2 are in using it with things that read their entire input before producing any output, or line of input, line of output.

Comment: @zdim, @ikegami: Thanks to mention the IPC::Run, I was not aware of it. It seems to me that it conveniently addresses some scenarios (e.g. their samba example simulating the interaction with a user) but in general it will have the same problem as the popen2. Let's say that instead of the `cat`(which is obviously just for a sake of the example) I have some archiving/encryption/compression/encoding utility. I don't now how many characters it will produce or how the output will end and so I can't use `pump $h until something in the output`.

Comment: @Shawn: I want a reliable code that will always work. Reading one line here, other there will not work with any process and even the one where it works may surprise one day.

Comment: @Shawn, ikegami: Thanks for the select tip. I will try to experiment with that later. After first reading of the docs it is not clear to me how to use it.

Comment: @David L., None of what you said makes any sense. If you can do it with `select`, you can do it a million times simpler using IPC::Run. As far as I can tell, you simply need `run [ 'utility'], \$to_send, \my $received;`. Use sub refs instead of scalar refs if your needs are more complicated.

Comment: @DavidL. Great edit! I wish I can +1 again :)  But, as for that closing comment: It is possible to do what you seem to want (start an external program and repeatedly make it pass a lot of data?) -- can roll it all up with "primitives" (pipes, select/signals).  And it can be done with `open2` as well ... but these are inferior approaches, since you'd be doing _everything_ by hand, while there are well established modules that already have all that.  So, for learning it's probably great to go through it; in any other sense, the answer _is_: don't; use ready solutions. My 2c.

Comment: @DavidL. As for "_close the file handle from a different thread_" -- brrr, don't want that. Specially with threads which share many resources. There are ways to signal to a thread/fork what it should do (but then that's specific to threads/forks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your program stopped because the pipe to which it was writing became full.
2. The pipe to `cat` became full because `cat` stopped reading from it.
3. `cat` stopped because the pipe to which it was writing became full.
4. The pipe from `cat` became full because you program isn't reading from it.

So you have two programs waiting for each other to do something. This is a deadlock.

The low-level solution is to use `select` to monitor both ends of the pipe.

The high-level solution is to let [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/IPC::Run) or [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/IPC::Run3) do that hard work for you.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my $cnt_max = 100000;
my $cnt = 0;
run [ "cat" ],
   '<', sub { $cnt < $cnt_max ? $cnt++ . "\n" : undef };
```

Comment: Thanks for the select tip. I think that eventually I found the right docs: `https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html` So with the `can_read`/`can_write(timeout)` I can implement some polling. Well, with that it is doable even in a single thread but I don't consider it to be a proper solution. Depending on the particular process and timeout it may slow down the system (either with a lot of polling or slow communication with the process).

Comment: What? no! Don't poll.You're making me cry! Use `select` (from the same module), not `can_read` or `can_write`. Wait, what I am I saying. **Use IPC::Run!!**

Comment: As this is the only answer, so I select it as "accepted", because the topic was probably exhausted, especially in all the comments. Learning about the IPC::Run was certainly a great outcome. During the past 2 days I changed a lot of code to it and it became much more readable!

Comment: The code you added to your question doesn't work at all. See the code I've added to my answer.

Comment: Well, it runs after adding `use 5.26.0;` or replace the `say` with `print $cnt++.'\n'`. Unless you use Windows, there I had quite serious problems even with basic stdin/stdout functionality. Now I've tested it on a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.10, without installing any additional libraries or cpan modules.

Comment: In the code that you added it is the `cat` process that does the output, so it does not demonstrate further processing of the output in the perl script. But I feel that now we are moving definitely away from the original topic.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your example, so `run` apparently calls the sub repeatedly as long as it returns true so that it is not necessary to have the `while`. Nice.

Comment: Btw, just observation: when I execute my code and run `top` so I can see that the `run` apparently forked the `perl` process and so the two subs are running in parallel, consuming a low amount of memory, as the data are continuously being processed.

Comment: Same with what I posted, minus all the extra processes.